# How to evaluate $\int \left[\sqrt{\int xdx+\int x^{2}dx+\int x^{\frac{7}{2}}dx+\int x^{4}dx} \right]dx$ .

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I need help to evaluate
$$\int \left[\sqrt{\int x\mathrm{d}x+\int x^{2}\mathrm{d}x+\int x^{\frac{7}{2}}\mathrm{d}x+\int x^{4}\mathrm{d}x} \right]\mathrm{d}x$$
I am trying this question by evaluating separately each of

$$\int x\mathrm{d}x\qquad\int x^{2}\mathrm{d}x\qquad\int x^{\frac{7}{2}}\mathrm{d}x\qquad\text{and}\qquad\int x^{4}\mathrm{d}x$$

Now $$\int x\mathrm{d}x = \frac{x^{2}}{2}+C\quad \int x^{2}\mathrm{d}x=\frac{x^{3}}{3}+C_1\quad \int x^{\frac{7}{2}}\mathrm{d}x= \frac{x^{\frac{9}{2}}}{\frac{9}{2}}+C_2\quad\text{ and }\quad\int x^{4}\mathrm{d}x=\frac{x^{5}}{5}+C_3$$

Now the final integration is becoming $$\int \left[\sqrt{\frac{x^{2}}{2}+C+\frac{x^{3}}{3}+C_1+\frac{x^{\frac{9}{2}}}{\frac{9}{2}}+C_2+\frac{x^{5}}{5}+C_3}\right]\mathrm{d}x$$ But how to integrate further? Please help me out.

Comment: Try to combine the $C,C_j$’s into just $c$

Comment: OK. But how to solve after that? If I combine $C$ , $C_1$ , $C_2$  and $C_3$ together as '$c$' then also how to solve it?

Comment: where did you got this question from ?

Comment: wolfram gives "no result found in terms of standard mathematical functions"

Comment: Yes you are correct@pie.

Comment: If you can see Wolfram saying that it can't find an answer, you should provide more context or reasoning with your question. Do you want to get an approximation? Do you have reasons to suspect that there actually is an answer? Just throwing some math symbols together doesn't make for very good math.se questions.

Comment: You could expand using binomial theorem and get a closed form with an [Appell function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/AppellHypergeometricFunction.html) or [Lauricella function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LauricellaFunctions.html) potentially

Answer (score 3):

Your integral is of the form

$$\int \sqrt{f(x)}\, dx$$

where $f(x)$ is a quintic polynomial. If the polynomial $f$ has degree 3 or 4 and has no repeated roots, you have an [elliptic integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral), a highly studied type of function. In your case, the polynomial may or may not have repeated roots (depending on the constant term), but even if there are no repeated roots, it has a higher degree. I would think of this as a `cousin' of an elliptic integral. Presumably it doesn't have a name as Wolfram couldn't find it.